# カレントディレクトリ以外の場所からTerraformを実行する方法

Tags: terraform

通常、Terraformは、*.tf(main.tf)ファイルがある場所をカレントディレクトリとして、次のコマンドを実行します。

```
terraform apply --auto-approve
```

例えば、Shellから複数のTerraformを利用するときなど、カレントディレクトリ以外の場所から、Terraformを利用することは可能でしょうか？

```
cd hoge_folder
terraform apply --auto-approve
cd ../fuga_folder
terraform apply --auto-approve
```

となってしまいます。

```
terraform apply --working_folder=hoge_folder
```

などのようなことができないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マニュアルを見てみると `-chdir` というオプションがあるようです。

> #### [Passing a Different Configuration Directory](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply#passing-a-different-configuration-directory)
>
> If your workflow relies on overriding the root module directory, use [the `-chdir` global option](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands#switching-working-directory-with-chdir) instead, which works across all commands and makes Terraform consistently look in the given directory for all files it would normally read or write in the current working directory.

Comment: ありがとうございます。期待通りのことができました。
terraform -chdir=working_folder plan